# Regex: Remove empty sections from INI (Text) files where the files could contain multiple such sections

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, ini, find-replace, regex-replace

I have below resultant php.ini file, after I was able to remove the comments & spaces thro' some simple Regex find/replace steps:

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
....
....
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[imap]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off
[ODBC]
....
....
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "{PHP_Dir_Path}\extras\curl\cacert.pem"
[openssl]
[ffi]
```

As you can see, there are multiple occurrences where multiple empty sections(sections which doesn't contain any semicolon-less(non-commented) lines) in this file, and I can't bring myself to make a regex find/replace pattern that could let me remove all such empty sections in one go, so that it becomes like below:

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
....
....
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off
[ODBC]
....
....
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "{PHP_Dir_Path}\extras\curl\cacert.pem"
```

Can anyone help me out achieve, what I need ?

Comment: Maybe something like this will suffice: [`^\[.*+\n(?=\s*\[)`](https://regex101.com/r/xvoRlo/1)

Comment: I saw it fails for the last element `[ffi]` - maybe better: [`^\[.*+\n?(?!\s*[^\[])`](https://regex101.com/r/1BUh4C/1) (can't answer atm, busy)

Comment: That does the job perfect, thanks a lot, and you can take your time, in converting this to an answer, maybe tomorrow or day-after, whenever, thanks again  !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea to [look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after lines starting with `[` for another opening bracket (or end).

```
^\[.*+\s*+(?![^\[])
```

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1BUh4C/3) - If using NP++ uncheck: [ ] `.` dot matches newline

- [`^`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) line start (NP++ default)
- `\[` matches an opening bracket
- `.*+` [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) besides newline ([without giving back](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html))
- `\s*+`  any amount of [whitespace](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) (also *possessive* to reduce backtracking)
- `(?!` negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to fail on the defined condition `)` which is:
- `[^\[]` a [character that is not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) an opening bracket

In short words it matches lines starting with `[` up to *eol* and any amount of whitespace...
if there is either no character ahead or the next character is another `[` opening bracket.
*Side note*: Its positive equivalent is [`^\[.*+\s*+(?=\[|\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZWqy0V/3) where `\z` matches *end of string*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to match if there is a ] followed by a new line and then a [, with the following regex:

```
\]\n\[
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed by your comment, that would just get the ][ characters, so you could try this instead:

```
(\[(\w)+\]\n)(?!\w)
```

This will match a title that is not followed by a word in the next line.

**EDIT2:**

My previous answer would not get the last section if it was empty, so I changed it to check the newline OR end of file.

```
(\[(\w)+\])(\n(?!\w)|$)
```

Comment: But this will keep the section title intact, as I mentioned I want to remove the entire empty section, incl. section title(and brackets), all such sections.

Comment: That's right, my bad! You can select only the titles of empty sections with this, which will look for titles that are not followed by a word:
(\[(\w)+\]\n)(?!\w) (I will edit the answer)

Comment: Yes your second suggestion seems to do the job well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your regex-engine to use the single-line aka "dotall" mode. Then you can easily pick out any bracketed strings that are only separated by a newline:

```
 /\[[^\]]+\]\s\[[^\]]+\]/gs
```

The `s` flag enables "dotall" mode.

**Update:** Overlooked one obvious problem with my solution. It gets a bit more complicated now, using a lookahead `(?:\s(?=\[))`. Also extra caution needs to be taken to capture the last empty section, which is done with the `|$` part. [Regexr link updated...](https://regexr.com/6ppek)

```
 /\[[^\]]+\](?:\s(?=\[)|$)/gs
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer, but bad luck, the Text editors I am using are either Sublime Text or Notepad++ and I don't know how to enable such feature in those editors' settings, any workaround that could work just like your above answer and provide the needed result ?

Comment: Oops, one more thing I forgot to add, if you see in the results in your regexr link, your regex is also removing the section headers that actually contain non-commented lines, like `[mail function]`, and that section has lines such as `SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off`. So can you please improve your answer so it doesn't remove those non-empty section headers ?

Comment: @VickyDev Did that even though it won't be any help with the most recent npp, I checked it. Couldn't check sublime though. Please state your regex environment beforehand next time.

Comment: Sure will take care of mentioning this upfront now onwards, thanks !!